# Troubles isolating target cell in recursive sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a table, let's say it looks like this:

```
c | p
=====
|1|3|
|2|1|
|7|5|
```

`c` stands for `current` and `p` stands for `parent`

Given a `c` value of `2` I would return its top most ancestor (which has no parent) this value is `3`. Since this is a self referencing table, I figured using CTE would be the best method however I am very new to using it. Nevertheless, I gave it a shot:

```
WITH Tree(this, parent) AS
  ( SELECT c ,p
   FROM myTable
   WHERE c = '2'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT M.c ,M.p
     FROM myTable M
     JOIN Tree T ON T.parent = M.c )
SELECT parent
FROM Tree
```

However this returns:

`1`
`3`

I only want `3` though. I have tried putting `WHERE T.parent <> M.c` but that doesn't entirely make sense. Neadless to say, I am a little confused for how to isolate the grandparent.

Comment: do you always want to return the gradparent or do you want to return the top most ancestor?  Because the former can be done with 2 joins and the latter would take a technique such as a recursive cte.  Also will the top parent always actually have a record in the table too?

Comment: @Matt Thank you for clarifying... the top most ancestor is what I am after and no the top most ancestor will not have a parent. I'll update my question.

Comment: I get they won't have a parent but I am wondering if there is still a record in the tale e.g. Child 3, Parent NULL?

Comment: @Matt no, that is what is throwing me off... the Child 3, Parent NULL scenario will not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (Child INT, Parent INT)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (1,3),(2,1),(7,5)

;WITH cteRecursive AS (
    SELECT
       OriginalChild = Child
       ,Child
       ,Parent
       ,Level = 0
    FROM
       @Table
    WHERE
       Child = 2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
       c.OriginalChild
       ,t.Child
       ,t.Parent
       ,Level + 1
    FROM
       cteRecursive c
       INNER JOIN @Table t
       ON c.Parent = t.Child
)


SELECT TOP 1 TopAncestor = Parent
FROM
    cteRecursive
ORDER BY
    Level DESC
```

Use a recursive cte to Recuse up the tree until you cannot.  Keep track of the Level of recursion, then take the last level of recursions parent and you have the top ancestor.

And just because I wrote it I will add in if you wanted to find the top ancestor of every child.  The concept is still the same but you would need to introduce a `row_number()` to find the last level that was recursed.

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (Child INT, Parent INT)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (1,3),(2,1),(7,5),(5,9)

;WITH cteRecursive AS (
    SELECT
       OriginalChild = Child
       ,Child
       ,Parent
       ,Level = 0
    FROM
       @Table

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
       c.OriginalChild
       ,t.Child
       ,t.Parent
       ,Level + 1
    FROM
       cteRecursive c
       INNER JOIN @Table t
       ON c.Parent = t.Child
)

, cteTopAncestorRowNum AS (
    SELECT
       *
       ,TopAncestorRowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OriginalChild ORDER BY Level DESC)
    FROM
       cteRecursive
)

SELECT
    Child = OriginalChild 
    ,TopMostAncestor = Parent
FROM
    cteTopAncestorRowNum
WHERE
    TopAncestorRowNum = 1
```